# Generate signed APK with jks React Native

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I am changing one of my old apps on the android play store from a native android app (written in java) to one written in react native.  My old apps were signed with a jks when I would release it to the play store, however according to [React Native Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) They use a keystore to sign their requests.  This will cause a problem given that play store will reject any app updates I submit that don't have it signed by jks.  I have tried to do the generation normally through the documenation above but subsituting in my jks instead of the keystore and it fails with `can't access keystore`.  Was wondering if there was a way to generate my signed apk even through android studio? I tried to do that as well, but it doesn't seem to run correctly/crashes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I am an idiot.  Many posts have said `jks` and `keystore` are pretty much the exact same thing.  You can generate a signed apk with your jk with react native the same way as if you were to use a keystore you just need to make sure you have the alias right and everything else correct.